# scheduling events using shortest duration as greedy algorithm

Tags: algorithm, events, greedy

There is a list of events and I want to schedule maximum number of events in a day in a way that they don't conflict with each other and the events are scheduled based on short duration events being considered first. I have my code attached below which shows what I am trying to do, I know I am sorting them correctly based on their duration but further I am not able to schedule them without conflicts. Can someone please help me with this.

```
def shortest_duration(events):
    events.sort(key= lambda x: x[1]-x[0])
    print(events)
    finish =0
    ans=[]
    for event in events:
        if finish <= event[0]:
            finish= event[1]
            ans.append(event)
    return ans

events = [(420, 480), (420, 510), (450, 550), (480, 570), (510, 540), (540, 570), (540, 630), (570, 630)]

print(events)
print(shortest_duration(events))
```

Comment: Can you perhaps provide some explanation of what the numbers are? What does `(420, 488)` represent? Can some events occur simultaneously (i.e. meetings in multiple rooms, for example)? As written, your question can't be reasonably answered because it's missing critical information.

Comment: No it's just in one room . 420 in this case would be event start time and 488 event end time.

Comment: So what's the problem? Can you show us the output from your program? Can you tell us how the output differs from what you expect?

Comment: [(510, 540), (540, 570), (570, 630)], this is the output I am getting and If you see the event list in the question above , you will see it did not consider (420,480). This event can also be scheduled before (510,540).

Comment: Have you single-stepped your code in the debugger to see why that first event isn't being added? If you really have written a greedy algorithm (and the code looks correct), then the first event should be added to the answer.